# Feeding square voltage pulses into a step up transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, magnetics

I've wound a 5:54 turn transformer. I'm feeding it small voltage pulses in the input, but it seems like on the output, it "struggles" to achieve the output voltage (ie, it doesn't give me square voltage pulses). In the following photos, in green is the transformer voltage in the input and output for your reference.

[image]

[image]

The load added to the secondary is a resistor, although I've tried having it open circuited and the voltage response is similar. I've also tried using litz wire to see if it helps to output square voltage on the high side, to no results. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

EDIT: Green traces are transformer voltage (primary, then secondary on second photo), and blue is the respective current going in/out of the transformer (primary then secondary again).
Apologies yellow and purple are irrelevant to this question. The transformer is an RM12 core, with 24:5:24 turns (sec/prim/sec), so fully interleaved 5:54 transformer.

Comment: Which oscilloscope trace is which, exactly? Also, please show a schematic and a picture of the transformer.

Comment: @JonathanS. Added the requested info in the original post, unfortunately don't have a photo of the transformer available right now, but can post that later on. The circuit is a full bridge feeding +-Vin on the transformer (with some minor dead-time), and I've had connected a resistor on the high (output side).

Comment: Which frequency is your transformer tuned for?  If you do Fourier analysis, which frequencies are present in your square wave?

Comment: What are you probing with (particularly the secondary voltage)?

Comment: Reducing square wave input frequency temporarily from 100kHz to between 1/10 - 1/2 could help with analyzing transformer core permeability/reluctance?

Comment: @TimWilliams Transformer voltages are probed with a differential probe. Current is probed with a current probe

Comment: Your pictures are not making sense. Why is the 2nd one different to the first i.e. what changed. Please start again and don't have scope traces that are irrelevant in the pictures and don't change colours from one shot to the next. Explain what core you used. Explain how many turns were wound and state what operating frequencies were applied. How does 24:5:24 become 5:54 <-- not making sense of this.

Comment: @Andyaka First appears to be yel/mag = primary ends (green is the difference measured by some diff probe), second appears to be same but with probe across secondary. Is that correct, Grigoris?

Comment: @TimWilliams almost, yes. Green was the transformer terminals (first pic primary/second secondary side). Yellow/magenda were the low side Vgs that I left on, without much use in this case, apart from having a clean waveform to do triggering with. I did connect the transformer with the resonant tank I wanted, and it ended up working OK, so my problem appeares to be resolved in converter operation (!). Apologies for not making sense Andy, indeed the turns are 27:5:27 to make the resulting turns ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing on the transformer's secondary is ringing due to the transformer's leakage inductance forming a resonant circuit with the parasitic capacitances that are everywhere.

The solution is to dampen these high-frequency oscillations with a RC snubber network, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feuL13.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've eyeballed the component values but they should drastically reduce the ringing already, if not eliminate it. R1 will dissipate about 500mW (up to about a Watt). Power dissipation is directly proportional to the size of C1.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I will try adding a snubber tomorrow in lab. However, apart from the high-frequency ringing, you can notice that the average voltage (imagine the HF ringing gone), that the voltage slowly goes to its final value. It's kind of like it's trying to charge a parallel capacitance, but this being a wire-wound transformer I shouldn't have a problem with parasitic capacitances though?

Comment: @Grigoris I'm pretty sure this is an artifact from the ringing as well.